# Kernel module Makefile: No rule to make target

Tags: c, linux, makefile, module, linux-kernel

I wrote a simple Makefile to build all the .c files in the current directory into a Kernel module. I want the .ko output file to have the same name as the current directory.

Here's an example:

Before running the Makefile:

```
lab1/
  Makefile
  module_generic.c
  module_serial.c
```

After running the Makefile:

```
lab1/
  Makefile
  module_generic.c
  module_serial.c
  lab1.ko
```

Here's the Makefile I wrote:

```
directory := $(notdir $(PWD))

obj-m := $(addsuffix .o,$(directory))
$(directory)-objs := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

all:
    echo $($(directory)-objs)
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I run the `make` command I get `make[2]: ***  No rule to make target « /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/lab1.c »`.

My shell is in French but here's the entire output of the `make` command:

```
echo module_generic.o module_serial.o
module_generic.o module_serial.o
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.18/build M=/home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1 modules
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-source-4.15.18 »
make[2]: ***  Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/lab1.c », nécessaire pour « /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/lab1.o ». Arrêt.
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1] Error 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-source-4.15.18 »
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As you can see, I echo the content of `$(directory)-objs` which is `module_generic.o module_serial.o`. If I change in the Makefile `$(directory)-objs := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))` to `$(directory)-objs := module_generic.o module_serial.o` it does work.

Here's the Makefile now:

```
directory := $(notdir $(PWD))

obj-m := $(addsuffix .o,$(directory))
$(directory)-objs := module_generic.o module_serial.o

all:
    echo $($(directory)-objs)
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

My shell is in French but here's the entire output of the `make` command:

```
echo module_generic.o module_serial.o
module_generic.o module_serial.o
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.18/build M=/home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1 modules
make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-source-4.15.18 »
  CC [M]  /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/module_generic.o
In file included from /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/module_generic.c:1:0:
/home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/module_generic.h:12:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
  CC [M]  /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/module_serial.o
In file included from /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/module_serial.c:1:0:
/home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/module_serial.h:9:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
 };
 ^
/home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/module_serial.h:11:12: warning: ‘open_port’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Wunused-function]
 static int open_port(struct user_data **user_data);
            ^~~~~~~~~
/home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/module_serial.h:12:12: warning: ‘release_port’ declared ‘static’ but never defined [-Wunused-function]
 static int release_port(struct user_data **user_data);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  LD [M]  /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/lab1.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/lab1.o
see include/linux/module.h for more information
  CC      /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/lab1.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/ens/AP56590/Bureau/lab1/lab1.ko
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-source-4.15.18 »
```

I'm not sure what's the difference between `$(directory)-objs := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))` and `$(directory)-objs := module_generic.o module_serial.o` since both echo the same thing.